# How to use same column in multiple condition in case statement in Bigquery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, case

I have to use a particular column as 2 different condition in same case statement with count distinct in SQL Bigquery, Please let me know how

Data:

```
 cus  month   col1

 1   202207   A
 1   202207   Z
 2   202209   B
 2   202210   Z 
 2   202211   A
 3   202211   B
 4   202212   Z
```

Desired output :

```
 cus count_distinct_month
  1   1
  2   3
```

Exisiting sql query:

```
count(distinct (case when (month >= 202207 and month <= 202301) and col1 in ('A','B','C','D','E','F') and (col1 ='Z')  then month end)) as count_distinct_month
```

This query is throwing me 0 result, please help on the same

Comment: hmmm, is col1 defined in more than one table?

Comment: No, it is working for month column but but not working for "col1" column. Not understanding where is the miss here

Comment: col1 is a string column

Comment: col1 can't be 'z' and something else at the same time

Comment: why cant it be? i need a condition where col1 is either A,B,C,D, E or F and also col1 is Z

Answer (score 1):

consider below approach

```
select cus, count(distinct month) as count_distinct_month
from your_table 
where month between 202207 and 202301
and col1 in ('A','B','C','D','E','F', 'Z')
group by cus
having countif(col1 ='Z') > 0 and countif(col1 in ('A','B','C','D','E','F')) > 0
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

You can use below for testing

```
with your_table as (
  select 1 cus, 202207 month, 'A' col1 union all
  select 1, 202207, 'Z' union all
  select 2, 202209, 'B' union all
  select 2, 202210, 'Z' union all
  select 2, 202211, 'A' union all
  select 3, 202211, 'B' union all
  select 4, 202212, 'Z' 
)
select cus, count(distinct month) as count_distinct_month
from your_table 
where month between 202207 and 202301
and col1 in ('A','B','C','D','E','F', 'Z')
group by cus
having countif(col1 ='Z') > 0 and countif(col1 in ('A','B','C','D','E','F')) > 0
```

Comment: no i'm getting 0 results

Comment: as you can see - when i use your sample data - I do have expected result ! so you might misrepresenting your real data then, I added query with test data so you can try by yourself

Answer (score 1):

Filter the rows of the table with your conditions for the `month` and `col1` and aggregate:

```
SELECT cus, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT month) AS count_distinct_month
FROM tablename
WHERE month >= 202207 AND month <= 202301 AND col1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'Z')
GROUP BY cus
HAVING COUNTIF(col1 ='Z') > 0 AND COUNT(DISTINCT col1) > 1;
```

The `HAVING` clause makes sure that for each `cus` in the results there is at least 1 row with `col1 ='Z'` and at least another row with `col1 IN ('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F')`.

Comment: Yes, they can be of different months. But with this query i'm getting 0 result

Comment: @anaghas Then either you did not explain your requirement correctly or there are no rows in the table that satisfy the conditions that you want to apply. Check this working demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kXA1sNADqa9FX4zFXnxhQW/0 (for MySql where I changed `COUNTIF(col1 ='Z')` with the MySql equivalent `SUM(col1 ='Z')`)